# MySQL Set First value that is -1 to a number?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a data table:
`player1, player2, player3, player4`
And they are each an `int` that defaults to `-1`.  How would I set the first one (`player1` is first, `player4` is last) that is -1 to a number?

Example:
`player1, player2, player3, player4`
`-1, -1, -1, -1`
`player1` is the first value that is -1, so we set it to 4.

Comment: You can't order an update so you won't be guaranteed an order.

Comment: There's no way to set it to the first possible opening?

Comment: MySQL makes no guarantee on the order the rows are returned unless an `ORDER BY` is given. And alternative solution like Gordon's might work.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
update table t
    set player1 = (case when player1 = -1
                        then <a number> else player1 end),
        player2 = (case when player1 <> -1 and player2 = -1
                        then <a number> else player2 end),
        player3 = (case when player1 <> -1 and player2 <> -1 and player3 = -1
                        then <a number> else player3 end),
        player4 = (case when player1 <> -1 and player2 <> -1 and player3 <> -1 and player4 = -1
                        then <a number> else player4 end);
```

Comment: I think I want the `end` after `<a number>` if I'm reading it right?

Comment: No, you're updating every field every time you run the query, so you need the else to make sure it's unchanged if the case test is false.

Comment: I've tried running: `UPDATE teams
SET player1 = (case when player1 <> -1 then 8 else -1 end)
WHERE id=7;` but nothing happens.  (Happens when I remove the WHERE statement also).  Any idea why?